# How do I center an object in its parent?

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, transforms, constraints

I have 2 objects.

Their dimensions are completely identical.

I have applied all transformations, rotations and scales.

Their locations are 0, 0, 0.

I have tried parenting the objects, both in relations and object constraints. Neither parenting nor making them separate objects has any effect.

Fiddling with their origins has no effect.

And yet, I can never get the objects in the same position. They are always off:

[image: Off-center objects]

How in the world is one supposed to center two objects into each other? It seems that no matter what I do, they are never in the center of each other, despite having exactly the same dimensions.

As you can see the problem still occurs in-game:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is essentially [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/142362/35559). With your current Pivot Point settings, ('Median',) the center of your object is considered to be the mean location of its vertices, not the center of its bounding box.

- Set Pivot to 'Bounding Box'
- Edit Mode, all selected, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>,Cursor to Selected
- Object mode, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> Origin to Cursor
- .. and set the location to 0..

...for both objects.

Comment: P.S. I don't think a _Limited Dissolve_ on the cut card, getting rid of the unnecessary triangulation, would do you any harm.