# How to get access to new faces created by array modificator in Python

Tags: python, modifiers

How to get access to new faces created by array modificator in Python?
Now I use:

```
   me = bpy.context.object.data
   bm = bmesh.new() 
   bm.from_mesh(me) 
   for f in bm.faces:
     ...
```

But new faces from not applied array dont visible by this way.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMesh.from_object and https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Context.html?highlight=evaluated_depsgraph_get#bpy.types.Context.Context.evaluated_depsgraph_get an example here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194347/how-i-can-find-the-the-3d-location-of-the-vertex-groups-in-mixamo-character/194378#194378

Comment: @lemon, thank you very much!